# building a table using cout

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am generating 20 random numbers between 1 and 10.  I then use a switch statement to get the count for each possible random number between 1 and 10.

I was wondering if there is an alternate way to display a series of variables using a loop rather than building a table manually like I do below:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        a[i] = generateRandomNumber();

        //record the counts for each possible random number
        switch (a[i]) {
            case 0: ++count_1; break;
            case 1: ++count_2; break;
            case 2: ++count_3; break;
            case 3: ++count_4; break;
            case 4: ++count_5; break;
            case 5: ++count_6; break;
            case 6: ++count_7; break;
            case 7: ++count_8; break;
            case 8: ++count_9; break;
            case 9: ++count_10; break;
        }
    }   

    //output the counts to the screen
    cout << "N  Count\n";
    cout << "1: " << ++count_1 << "\n";
    cout << "2: " << ++count_2 << "\n";
    cout << "3: " << ++count_3 << "\n";
    cout << "4: " << ++count_4 << "\n";
    cout << "5: " << ++count_5 << "\n";
    cout << "6: " << ++count_6 << "\n";
    cout << "7: " << ++count_7 << "\n";
    cout << "8: " << ++count_8 << "\n";
    cout << "9: " << ++count_9 << "\n";
    cout << "10: " << ++count_10 << "\n";
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like an array?

Comment: Are you asking how to *display a series* in a loop, or *build a table* in a loop?  Or both?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to only have to use 'cout' once inside of a loop rather than write out each line for each possible random number.

Comment: Put your `count...` values in any container that associates an integer with a value.  Like an array.  Or a map.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array to keep count of the frequency of occurence of all the numbers -:

```
int count[10];
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    count[i] = 0;  // Initializing count
}

for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
{
    a[i] = generateRandomNumber();
    count[a[i]]++;
}

//output the counts to the screen
cout << "N  Count\n";
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    cout << i + 1 << " : " << count[i] << "\n";
}
```